# SQL exclude rows without subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I have these tables:

```
PERSON               COURSE               PERSON_COURSE
+----+----------+    +----+----------+    +------+------+
| ID | Name     |    | ID | Name     |    | P_ID | C_ID |       
+----+----------+    +----+----------+    +------+------+
| P1 | Person 1 |    | C1 | Course 1 |    | P1   | C1   |
| P2 | Person 2 |    | C2 | Course 2 |    | P1   | C2   |
| P3 | Person 3 |    | C3 | Course 3 |    | P3   | C2   |
+----+----------+    +----+----------+    | P3   | C3   |
                                          +------+------+
```

and I want to select *all persons which does not attend course C1*.

So I'm using:

```
select p.id
from person p
where p.id not in (
    select pc.p_id 
    from person_course pc
    where pc.c_id != 'C1')
```

Now, I'm wondering if it's possible to obtain the same result without using a subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is a left join, trying to match people with the course and including only people where there is no match;

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person_course pc
  ON p.id = pc.p_id
 AND pc.c_id = 'C1'
WHERE pc.c_id IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a58f5/2).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all persons which does not attend course **C1**.

You could use aggregation:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.NAME
FROM PERSON P
LEFT JOIN PERSON_COURSE PC
  ON P.ID = PC.P_ID
GROUP BY P.ID, P.NAME
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN PC.C_ID = 'C1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/442734)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║   Name   ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║ P2 ║ Person 2 ║
║ P3 ║ Person 3 ║
╚════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out that you can do this using a subquery, but it is not the one in the question.  Instead:

```
select p.id
from person p
where p.id not in (select pc.p_id 
                   from person_course pc
                   where pc.c_id = 'C1'
---------------------------------^
                  );
```

(Although I prefer `NOT EXISTS` for this logic, I am keeping this as similar to your logic as possible.)

Be careful with double negatives.